# Error with formatting time in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios7.1

I am trying to format the date of a blog post pulled from an RSS feed to be displayed in a table cell. I set the string "dateString" equal to the date received from the XML parser and log the results. Then, I convert the date to a new format, log it to the console, and I receive "null." Which in return gives me a time interval of 0, and displays "seconds ago" in my cell. I think there could be an error in my date format, but I checked many sources.

```
NSString *dateString = nil;
dateString = [datearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Date Posted: %@", dateString);//Log date posted
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"New Date: %@", date);//Log date posted
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"Time interval %f", timeInterval);
NSString *newTime = [timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:timeInterval];
NSLog(@"New Time %@", newTime);
cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newTime];
```

Console Log:

```
2014-06-13 15:43:41.555 Cazenovia High School[13489:60b] Date Posted: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 13:33:44 +0000
2014-06-13 15:43:41.556 Cazenovia High School[13489:60b] New Date: (null)
2014-06-13 15:43:41.557 Cazenovia High School[13489:60b] Time interval 0.000000
2014-06-13 15:43:41.558 Cazenovia High School[13489:60b] New Time seconds ago
```

Edits:
Added the following lines, but still no change...

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
```

[image]

Comment: Try settings the date formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: @rmaddy I made the edits above, still no change.

Comment: on my side that is what the console logs holds after copying and pasting your code: `New Date: 2013-08-22 13:33:44 +0000` and `Time interval -25591284.694682`. that looks correct to me. what is actual `locale`?

Comment: @holex Added an image of my console. My local is Eastern US. I have cleaned the project and the build folder as well as deleted derived data in the project organizer so the error isn't from cached information.

Comment: @holex My project can be found here: https://github.com/rileylloyd24/Cazenovia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was quite clear after running the project, because it seems there is an extra *new-line* character at tail of the `dateString`.

technically, which string you are working with is `"Thu, 22 Aug 2013 13:33:44 +0000\0x0a"`, that is why the parser cannot work with it using that formatter.

---

I've modified the formatter to `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ\n` and it works properly now, that is how my console looks:

[image]